# Songs not showing up on Lumia 920 default music player

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-920, music

Yesterday I thought I was tired of listening to the same list of music I have on my phone, so I went ahead and plugged in the USB cable to my laptop (running Linux Ubuntu), deleted all the songs I had on my phone and copied a couple of new songs to my phone storage. However, this morning I happened to find out that none of the songs I transfered is showing in the music player list. I was wondering if anyone else has had the same or a similar issue?

Comment: Are you saying you did this directly through the file system?

Comment: Yup, just like how I've always done it. Note that I didn't have any problems doing this in the past. However, I've never done it from a Linux machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your current arrangement will not suffice in achieving the end goal. This is a classic case of the fundamental differences between *nix and Windows based systems.

Due to the different ways in which both these operating systems handle files and file names, it is currently not possible to use the Linux file system to drop files and have them recognized on a Windows Phone.

Your best bet is to use the following steps:

1. Since you have some files already transferred from your Linux box to your phone, borrow someones Windows machine or install a virtual machine running any version of Windows.
2. Transfer those files from your phone to the Windows machine and back in to your phone. Yes, you read that right.

Now, your phone will recognize the newly added files.

If you want to voice your frustration about this issue, consider voting on one or more of these forums:

- ["linux phone connector (like the mac connector) for ex. Ubuntu"](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2281975-linux-phone-connector-like-the-mac-connector-for)
- ["Sync with other OS platforms like Linux, BSD, etc."](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2414010-sync-with-other-os-platforms-like-linux-bsd-etc-)
- ["Make lumia phones compatible with linux based OS for updating and file transfers"](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3558319-make-lumia-phones-compatible-with-linux-based-os-f)

Comment: Tried your steps, and it actually worked!! I was under the impression that the phone would behave as an external storage when connected via a USB cable, but apparently, I was wrong. thanks!!

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using a Windows device, still not showing any of the new songs I added except one. How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: What phone is it?